# OperationalError: near ",": syntax error - SQLITE3

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite, jupyter

This is my code (from the "Python for Data Analysis" book):

```
import sqlite3

query = """ CREATE TABLE test (a VARCHAR(20), b VARCHAR(20)), c REAL, d INTEGER); """
con = sqlite3.connect('mydata.sqlite')
con.execute(query)
```

This is the error I get:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-702795376e74> in <module>()
      1 con = sqlite3.connect('mydata.sqlite')
----> 2 con.execute(query)

OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

I tried with single and triple quotes around the code, checked the commas, but I can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the brackets? **I can see 3 opening ( and 4 closing )**.
Looks like you need to remove one of the two closing for b `VARCHAR(20))`

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
query = "CREATE TABLE test (a VARCHAR(20), b VARCHAR(20), c REAL, d INTEGER)";
```

instead of yours

Answer (score 1):

Always count your brackets and no need for triple `"` here.

```
import sqlite3

query = " CREATE TABLE test (a VARCHAR(20), b VARCHAR(20), c REAL, d INTEGER); "
con = sqlite3.connect('mydata.sqlite')
con.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are using Pandas - you don't need to care of "create table ..." things. Pandas does it for you:

```
In [100]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [101]: df
Out[101]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  3
2  0  4  1
3  0  2  0
4  0  3  1

In [102]: conn = sqlite3.connect('c:/temp/test.sqlite')

In [103]: df.to_sql('test', conn, index=False)

In [104]: df2 = pd.read_sql('select * from test', conn)

In [105]: df2
Out[105]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  3
2  0  4  1
3  0  2  0
4  0  3  1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'm gonna look into that